# Resharper QuickDoc is Empty for .NET Types

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

When attempting to view documentation for any inbuilt .NET type via Resharper's "QuickDoc" I get an empty dialog:

[image]

Selecting "Read more" takes me to MS's new documentation site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=netframework-4.7

Is there some way I can rectify this so I can view documentation in Visual Studio once again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating Visual Studio and including the .NET4.7 targeting/sdk components appears to have fixed the problem.